# What is the purpose of adding hops BEFORE the hop schedule?

Tags: hops

I'm brewing an extract brew from NB called Waldo Lake Amber. I've never seen this in their instructions before. It is requesting that I add 1 oz of Cacade hops "directly into the boil kettle" immediate after the instruction to "collect and heat 2.5 gallons of water." After this hop addition I am to add the specialty grain until the water reaches 170*, then at boiling I am to add the malt syrup as normal. Once it begins to boil again, the hop schedule starts at this point.

It has never asked me to add hops prior to the normal hop schedule. What is the purpose of this?

In addition, the hops get all over the specialty grain steeping bag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It just so happens that Waldo Lake Amber is my recipe.  I designed that kit for NB.  The technique is called First Wort Hopping and produces increased hop flavor and a smooth, mellow bitterness.  Sounds like they kinda screwed up my directions.  The right way to do it is to steep the grains, then when that's done and the bag with them has been removed, add the FWH and let them sit in the kettle for 15-20 min,  Then proceed with rest of the extract additions.

Comment: Which temperature would you recommend for Wyeast 1450 Dennys Favorite (Incidentally, is that you or a namesake?) that NB told me to purchase for this batch?

Comment: I apologize but I messed up while trying a new strategy and had to dump all the gunk from the kettle into the carboy. Would I need to modify the temperature of the yeast due to that mistake?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "modify the temp of the yeast", but I'm pretty sure the answer is no.